# Magnolia Frog Rain

Tags: plot-explanation, magnolia

What does the frog rain in **Magnolia (1999)** mean? I got answers leading to Bible exodus 8:2 which is: *"But if you refuse to let them go, behold, I will smite your whole territory with frogs."*
I know the movie is all about 8:2 but since the frog rain makes things better in the movie, I couldn't understand it clearly. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 4):

This was discussed in a [Brightlightsfilm](http://brightlightsfilm.com/short-takes-cinematography-but-it-did-happen-paul-thomas-andersons-magnolia/#.VZBKPPlViko) inteview with the Director/Writer Paul Thomas Anderson:

> **Of all things, why frogs?**
>
> *It truly came from a slightly gimmicky and exciting place. I’d read about rains of frogs in the works of Charles Fort, who was a
> turn-of-the-century writer who wrote mainly about odd phenomena.
> Michael Penn was the one who turned me on to Fort, and who, when I
> went to one of Michael’s shows in New York once, made reference on
> stage to “rains of frogs.” At that moment I just went, Wow! How cool
> and scary and fun to do that would be – and what does it mean?*
>
> *So I just starting writing it into the script. It wasn’t until after I
> got through with the writing that I began to discover what it might
> mean, which was this: You get to a point in your life, and shit is
> happening, and everything’s out of your control, and suddenly, a rain
> of frogs just makes sense. You’re staring at a doctor who’s telling
> you something is wrong, and while we know what it is, we have no way
> of fixing it. And you just go, so what you’re telling me, basically,
> is that it’s raining frogs from the sky.*
>
> *I’m not someone who’s ever had a special fascination with UFO’s or
> supernatural phenomena or anything, but I guess I just found myself at
> a point where I was going through some shitty stuff and I was ready
> for some sort of weird religion experience, or as close as I could get
> to one.*
>
> *So then I began to decipher things about frogs and history, things
> like this famous notion that, as far back as the Romans, people have
> been able to judge the health of a society by the health of its frogs.
> The health of a frog, the vibe of a frog, the texture of a frog, its
> looks, how much wetness is on it, everything. The frogs are a
> barometer for who we are as people. We’re polluting ourselves, we’re
> killing ourselves, and the frogs are telling us so, because they are
> all getting sick and deformed. And I didn’t even know it was in the
> Bible until Henry Gibson gave me a copy of the Bible, bookmarked to
> the appropriate frog passage.*
>
> **What made you decide to use the sequences dealing with episodes of weird historical coincidence as a framing device for the film?**
>
> ***In a way, it’s a promise. A promise that, hey, look at these three stories which, to whatever extent are true or not, are weird and fantastic and filled with amazing coincidence – and that, if you gave me three hours, I will give you a story that is just as filled with weird and fantastic coincidence as they are, because “this stuff does happen.”***

Comment: so are the frogs like miracles in the movie ?

Comment: @icey - The original inspiration was apparently the works of Charles Fort rather than the biblical plague. That was added later